# How to delete a rails generate uploader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Ruby web app in Cloud9. I recently installed the gem 'carrierwave' to create avatar pictures for users.

After installing, I ran `$ rails generate uploader Avatar`
and it created a new "uploaders" folder with the file "avatar_uploader.rb" in the path: app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb.

This file looks like

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
end
```

I later decided that I do not want to use CarrierWave in my application (I want to use a different file uploading gem). How do I:

1) reverse "$ rails generate uploader Avatar" and delete the "uploaders" folder?

2) delete the gem 'carrierwave'?

Thanks!

Comment: try this: rails d(estroy) uploader Avatar. for controllers, views and models that works.

Comment: it worked, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rails destroy uploader Avatar`, but I think is better to remove the `uploaders` folder as are not going to use it.

Also remove the gem from the `Gemfile`, and don't forget removing the initializer and the migrations if you added.

If you are using a VCS (like git) you can undo the code with a `revert` commit.